# Preseve last Flot crosshair line and legend data after data refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

Edit:

After miro pointed out a flaw with how I was updating the plot I went back and rewrote the example. Now my crosshair is staying active after a data refresh unlike before which is good but the "y" value in my legend is failing to update at all. What needs to be done in this updated code to make the "y" value reflect the current position of the crosshair?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U9ryR/2/

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var highPoint=0;
        var highCount=0;

        $(function() {
            function getPoints() {
                var dataPoints = [];
                for (var i=0; i<=100; i++) {
                    if (i == highPoint && highCount < 20) {
                        dataPoints[i]=[i,8];
                        highCount++;
                    } else {
                        var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
                        dataPoints[i]=[i,randomnumber];
                    }
                    if (highCount == 20) { highCount = 0; }
                }
                if (highPoint == 100) { highPoint=0; }
                if (highCount == 19) { highPoint++; }
                return dataPoints;
            }    
            var plot = $.plot("#placeholder",
                    [{ data: getPoints(highPoint,highCount),         
                        label: "y = 0"}], {
                            series: {
                                lines: { show: true }
                            },
                       crosshair: { mode: "x" },
                       grid: { hoverable: true, autoHighlight: false },
                       yaxis: { min: 0, max: 10 }
            });

            var legends = $("#placeholder .legendLabel");
            legends.each(function () {
                $(this).css('width', $(this).width());
            });

            var updateLegendTimeout = null;
            var latestPosition = null;

            function updateLegend() {
                updateLegendTimeout = null;

                var pos = latestPosition;

                var axes = plot.getAxes();
                if (pos.x < axes.xaxis.min || pos.x > axes.xaxis.max ||
                    pos.y < axes.yaxis.min || pos.y > axes.yaxis.max)
                    return;

                var i, j, dataset = plot.getData();
                for (i = 0; i < dataset.length; ++i) {
                    var series = dataset[i];

                    // find the nearest points, x-wise
                    for (j = 0; j < series.data.length; ++j)
                        if (series.data[j][0] > pos.x)
                            break;

                    // now interpolate
                    var y, p1 = series.data[j - 1], p2 = series.data[j];
                    if (p1 == null)
                        y = p2[1];
                    else if (p2 == null)
                        y = p1[1];
                    else
                        y = p1[1] + (p2[1] - p1[1]) * (pos.x - p1[0]) / (p2[0] - p1[0]);

                    legends.eq(i).text(series.label.replace(/=.*/, "= " + y.toFixed(2)));
                }
            }

            function update() {
                $("h1").text(highPoint);
                $("h2").text(highCount);

                plot.setData([getPoints()]);
                plot.draw();
                $("#placeholder").bind("plothover",  function (event, pos, item) {
                    latestPosition = pos;
                    if (!updateLegendTimeout)
                        updateLegendTimeout = setTimeout(updateLegend, 50);
                });
                setTimeout(update, 100);
            }

            update();

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1></h1>
<h2></h2>
<div id="placeholder" style="width:500px;height:300px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

You are updating it wrong.

You are redrawing the entire graph every time.

Initialize the graph once and then just update the data.

These are the functions that you need to use.

```
plot.setData(...);
plot.draw();
```

Check this http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/realtime/index.html

View the source code and examine how it works and you'll be set.

Comment: Ok, so I did what you said and I now have the crosshair preserve but the I'm still having an issue with preserve the last y value of the crosshair. Here's my updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U9ryR/1/

Comment: There is something wrong with the variable scope. console.log(series.label); (put it right before .replace) it returns undefined... idk

Comment: I know this doesn't really solve anything but I added another header to display the "y" value to show that it is updating.

http://jsfiddle.net/U9ryR/3/

Two things here:

1) The "y" value is still dependent on the mouse moving. I would like it to update as the value changes whereever the crosshair is regardless of mouse movement.

2) Like you, I have no idea why the legend isn't updating.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/U9ryR/4/ - The problem was in series.label not being accessible from within the function (otside it's scrope). I changed it to legends.eq(i).text("y = " + y.toFixed(2)); and it works :)

Comment: Who knew, after almost 8 years ago this answer is still the best solution for the problems!